# how to use DontDestroyOnLoad?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, identifier

So this is probably quite easy but I've never used DontDestroyOnLoad() before and don't know what to do. I have some values in a script I'd like to keep when switching to another screen and I saw that DontDestroyOnLoad() could help me with that but it doesn't seem to work hers my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class data_transfer : MonoBehaviour
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
}
```

I get this error message: `Assets\scripts\data_transfer.cs(7,43): error CS1001: Identifier expected`
like I said this is probably relatively easy but I'm new to unity and C# so thank you if you want to help.

Comment: As for all `c#` methods in general: You use it inside a `method` .... it is then btw redundant to use `transform.gameObject` .. simply use `gameObject` directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DontDestroyOnLoad` is a method. You simply have to call it inside some other method, like `Awake` or `Start` For example like this

```
public class data_transfer : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
    }
}
```

`Awake` is called automatically by Unity when `GameObject` is instantiated, so this will prevent your object from being destroyed when new scene is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

According to Unity's [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html):

> Do not destroy the target Object when loading a new Scene. The load of a new Scene destroys all current Scene objects. Call DontDestroyOnLoad to preserve an Object during level loading.

You need to wrap the `DontDestroyOnLoad` call inside a function or one of the [MonoBehaviour](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html)'s built-in messages callbacks like [Awake](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) or [Start](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html).

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyClass: MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}
```